# How is $\left(\frac{n!}{(2n +1)!!}\right)^2 4^n = \left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n +1)!!}\right)^2 ?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

> How is $$\left(\frac{n!}{(2n +1)!!}\right)^2 4^n  = \left(\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n +1)!!}\right)^2 ?$$

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: $2n!! =2n\cdot (2n-2)\cdot...=2^n(n\cdot (n-1)\cdot...)=2^nn! $

Comment: Your denominators are obviously equal - you need to show that $(n!)^24^n = ((2n)!!)^2$. Do you know what the double factorial notation represents?

Comment: While StackExchange is a Q/A site, more than just a question is expected from the asker. Try to focus your question to an actual and specific problem you have faced. If you can, include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do. If you are stuck, provide definitions and your own background. Write down what you know and generally try to be constructive. If you can, provide motivation and context for the problem. This is meant to be an exchange, both ways, as the site name implies.

Comment: Okay I will try to do this as much as I can ..... thank you for your advice @CarlMummert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

1. Since the denominators of both expressions are the same, all you really need to prove is that $$ (n!)^24^n = ((2n)!!)^2 $$
2. $$\begin{align}(2n)!! &= 2n\cdot (2n-2)\cdot (2n-4)\cdots 2 \\&= 2\cdot n\cdot2\cdot(n-1)\cdot2\cdot(n-2)\cdots2\cdot 1 \\&= 2\cdot2\cdots 2\cdot n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 1\end{align}$$